# fatal: protocol 'git@https' is not supported

Tags: github

I have this message pushing my repo

```
C:\Users\sejjilali\Documents\Test forge>git push --set-upstream origin master
**fatal: protocol 'git@https' is not supported**
```

I don't know how to solve it, the problem is everything works normally in an other computer. Maybe it's because is a company one they landed me?

Here is my remote configuration:

```
C:\Users\sejjilali\Documents\Test forge>git remote -v
origin  git@https://github.com/Saifou/testForge.git (fetch)
origin  git@https://github.com/Saifou/testForge.git (push)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URLs for your `origin` remote are malformed:

> ```
> C:\Users\sejjilali\Documents\Test forge>git remote -v
> origin  git@https://github.com/Saifou/testForge.git (fetch)
> origin  git@https://github.com/Saifou/testForge.git (push)
> ```

The `git@` part comes from an SSH URL, but the rest looks like an HTTP URL. You can update them like so:

- If you want to use SSH URLs, something like

  ```
  git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Saifou/testForge.git
  ```

  Note that in this case we also convert a `/` to a `:` right after `github.com`.
- If you want to use HTTPS URLs, something like

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Saifou/testForge.git
  ```

Once that's done, run `git remote -v` again to ensure that both URLs have been updated.

Answer (score 2):

That's weird but once I had this error when I had '.git' in the path which is standard copy to clipboard from github

https://github.com/Saifou/testForge.git

change path to:

https://github.com/Saifou/testForge