# Unencrypted HTTP is not supported for Gitlab

Tags: android-studio, gitlab, git-remote, cloning

When I try to clone a project from GitLab to Android studio, I get an error saying clone failed and GitLab url is HTTP.

Error message is:

> Unencrypted HTTP is not supported for Gitlab.
> [image: img]

The same GitLab url is working for my teammates but not for me. Kindly suggest if I have to any setting changes in Android studio to resolve this issue, since I cannot do any changes to GitLab.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please always provide minimal reproducible post/question within codes you used. It seems this problem has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52929702/10452700)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012905/10452700).

Answer (score 2):

```
git config --global credential.gitlab.xxx.com.provider generic
```

replace gitlab.xxx.com with your repository address

---

git automatically recognizes the repository address and switches between different providers.

The latest gitlab providers have abandoned HTTP, but many older versions of standalone deployments are still HTTP, so we need to specify that our repositories use generic providers.

> https://code.fitness/post/2022/01/git-detecting-host-provider.html